# Linked list of chars in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, char

I'm trying to create a **linked list holding char type data.**

For some reason, the code does not work. The GCC compiler's warning for function "add_bottom_ListEl" is

"warning: passing argument 2 of 'add_bottom_listEl' makes integer from pointer without a cast"

and

"note: expected 'char' but argument is of type 'char * "

I suspect that there's something wrong about the way I use pointers, but I've tried many, many combinations, passing pointers to the function etc... But nothing seemed to work.

Here's main function and all the others used. MAX_CHAR is defined in all files (#define MAX_CHAR 30)

```
int main()
{
    char name[MAX_CHAR];
    scanf("%s", name);
    ListEl *head = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
    strcpy(head->name, name);
    head->next = NULL;
    printf("%s", head->name);
    add_bottom_listEl(head, name);
    print_listEl(head);
    return 0;
}
void add_bottom_listEl (ListEl *head, char name)
{
    ListEl *newEl;
    while(head->next!=NULL)
    {
        head=head->next;
    }
    newEl = (ListEl*) malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
    strcpy(newEl->name, name);
    newEl->next = NULL;
}
void print_listEl(ListEl* head)
{
    puts("print");
    ListEl* current = head;
    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        int i=1;
        printf("%d.%s\n", i, current->name);
        ++i;
        current = current -> next;
    }
}
```

The ListEl structure is just a regular element of a linked list

```
struct ListEl
{
    char name[MAX_CHAR];
    struct ListEl* next;
};
```

Obviously, I used

```
typedef struct ListEl ListEl;
```

Every linked list tutorial on the internet or this site is only showing how to handle lists with integers or numbers in general, but not arrays (chars). Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: `void add_bottom_listEl (ListEl *head, char name)` - `name` should be `char*`.

Comment: also make sure you have the functions declared before main

Comment: They are declared in seperate .c and .h files in my code

Comment: In your function that copies name, use strncpy passing MAX_CHAR -1 as the last parameter, then make sure you terminate name with [MAX_CHAR-1] = '\0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention in add_bottom_listEl is to modify and pass back head, then head has to be passed as a pointer to a pointer:

```
    void add_bottom_listEl(ListEl** head, char* name) {
        if ( head == NULL ) {         
    //head is invalid, do nothing
            return;
        }
    //Use calloc instead of malloc to initialise the memory area
        ListEl* newEl = (ListEl*)calloc(1, sizeof(ListEl));
    //Ensure only name of the permissible length is copied
        strncpy(newEl->name, name, MAX_CHAR-1);
    //No need to do this now...calloc will initialise it to NULL
        //newEl->next = NULL;

        if ( *head == NULL ) {
    //No nodes in list yet, this is the first
            *head = newEl;
        } else if ( *head != NULL ) {         
    //Find the end of the list
            while((*head)->next!=NULL) {
                *head = (*head)->next;
            }
        }
    //Add the new node to the list
        *head = newel;
   }
```

When you call this modified version of the function pass the address of the pointer:

```
    add_bottom_listEl(&head, name);
```

You can make your typedef more readable by doing this:

```
    typedef struct _listEl {
        char name[MAX_CHAR];
        struct _listEl* next;
    } ListEl;
```

Comment: Works just fine, there's just this one warning in the compiler which I don't quite understand - "warning: passing argument 1 of 'add_bottom_listEl' from incompatible pointer type". I implemented the code just like you wrote. Any idea where is that coming from?

Comment: Can you edit your original post and update the source as you have it now...label it under [Edit].

Comment: The warning is not there when I used your newest edit, thank you

Comment: Another edit, now you can remove your malloc in main and call the function to initialise the list, make sure head = NULL before calling.

Answer (score 2):

Your function "add_bottom_listEl" takes one character called "name", not a character array (or a pointer to a character). My guess is you want it to be:

```
add_bottom_listEl(ListEl *head, char *name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

`void add_bottom_listEl (ListEl *head, char name)`

should be

`void add_bottom_listEl (ListEl *head, char* name)`